# command git checkout deleted a few commits

Tags: git, commit, git-checkout

I used the command `git checkout 1234567` to view an old commit. 
Directly afterwards I checked another commit `git checkout 1234568` then I checked to master again `git checkout master`. But now my website is on a old version.

After I executed `git log --oneline` I realised that my two latest commits are lost! Why did this happen and is it possible to restore them?

Is it because I have to checkout to master again everytime before I checkout to another commit?

Comment: Did you make those two commits on `master` or while you had checked out one of the other commits?

Comment: what happens if you try to checkout them again ? did you lose their hash ?

Comment: Check git reflog to see what commits you have actually checked out

Comment: @EnricoCampidoglio yes i made these two commits on `master`. I did not made any commits while checking out the older commits

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Git, [nothing is lost](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Maintenance-and-Data-Recovery#_data_recovery) as long as you've committed it<sup>1</sup>.

You can use the [reflog](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) to get a *journal* of the commits that `master` has been pointing to through time by saying:

```
git reflog master
```

Once you've located the *latest one of your lost commits* in the [reflog](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog), you can make `master` point to it again by using [`git reset`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset).

For example, let's say that the latest lost commit is on the *4th* entry in the reflog. In order to restore it on `master` you would say:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard master@{4}
```

where `master@{4}` refers to the commit that `master` was pointing to 4 entries ago from where it is now.

Note that before you reset `master`, you should make sure that your working directory is *clean*, that is you don't have any *uncommitted* changes.

---

<sub>1. Well, *almost* nothing. Unreachable commits are going to *eventually* be deleted if enough time passes. By default, they will be kept around for 30 days but you can change that limit through the [`gc.reflogExpireUnreachable`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog#_options_for_code_expire_code) option.</sub>

Comment: I just executed `git checkout master` but my two latest commits are not appearing, it seems like they are really lost.

Comment: Did you look in the reflog?

Comment: If i execute `git reflog` then i see my latest commits and their SHA ID again, but im not sure how i can restore the latest commit again.

Comment: If you working directory is _clean_, use `git reset --hard <commit-sha>`. Please see my answer.

Comment: @EdwardBlack Great. If my answer solved your problem, you can tick the check mark on its right to mark it as accepted.

Comment: I know, and i will definitely do that because your answer is the most detailed.